# How to alias docker-compose to docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

From my understanding, `docker compose` is the latest version. This is the one at least I installed from docker official documentation.

I am working on a project that use `docker-compose` in their makefile.

How could I forward all the calls (and their arguments) from  `docker-compose` to  `docker compose` ?

I created an alias:
`alias docker-compose="docker compose"`

It works fine in terminal. But not in the make file.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

One solution I've come up with is to create a little script.

File: `/bin/docker-compose`

Content:

```
docker compose "$@"
```

Alternatively, in order to respect previous container naming convention (with underscore delimiter `_` over `-`):

```
docker compose --compatibility "$@"
```

To make the script executable: `sudo chmod +x /bin/docker-compose`.

You can check it with `docker-compose version`.

Comment: Note the container [naming convention changed](https://docs.docker.com/compose/cli-command-compatibility/#flags-that-will-not-be-implemented), with the old delimiter being `_` and the new version using `-`. You can add the `--compatibility` flag to force the old format, for drop-in compatibility with existing scripts.


Then content would be: `docker compose --compatibility "$@"`

Comment: Cool oneliner based on the awesome suggestion above:   
```
echo 'docker compose --compatibility "$@"' | sudo tee -a /usr/local/bin/docker-compose && sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Comment: This worked and without restarting my Ubuntu system, I just `source .bashrc` to reload the path

Answer (score 7):

You can symlink to the docker compose plugin binary. Mine is located at /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose. So just:

```
ln -f -s /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Answer (score 2):

Created this gist based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72187587/13011067) to make it easier:

```
sudo touch /usr/bin/docker-compose
echo 'docker compose --compatibility "$@"' | sudo tee /usr/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

https://gist.github.com/tatosjb/c477a5c09c4ad8fa67265032831ac94f

Answer (score 1):

Docker desktop comes with the option to alias docker compose v2 in `Settings > General`:

[image: Docker compose alias option]

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to avoid any additional scripts, I recommend you to :

- create your alias (in your ~/.profile | ~/.bash|zshrc file)

  alias docker-compose="docker compose --compatibility $@"
- source your ~/.profile|.zsh|bashrc file in your makefile.

Comment: don't think this work at all https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330615/special-characters-in-alias