# wp-env spawn docker-compose ENOENT on Raspberry Pi OS arm64

Tags: linux, wordpress, docker-compose, arm64

When try to execute

```bash
$ wp-env start
```

This is the error

```
⚠ Warning: could not find a .wp-env.json configuration file and could not determine if '/home/salsan/Projects/Wordpress' is a WordPress installation, a plugin, or a theme.
✖ spawn docker-compose ENOENT
Error: spawn docker-compose ENOENT
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn docker-compose',
  path: 'docker-compose',
  spawnargs: [
    '-f',
    '/home/salsan/.wp-env/8a634c95f96354e6faf10a0a35376956/docker-compose.yml',
    'down'
  ]
}
```

I read from Github issues for solve this problem, *[Enable Docker Compose V1/V2 compatibility mode in the Settings section of Docker Desktop](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/44513#issuecomment-1278167449)* , but on Raspberry Pi OS I don't have docker-desktop, if is this the problem how to solve it ?

My environment

> Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
>
> Kernel: Linux 5.15.84-v8+
>
> Architecture: arm64
>
> nvm 0.39.1  [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)
>
> node v18.14.2
>
> wp-env 5.13.0 ( globally installation )
>
> Docker version 23.0.1, build a5ee5b1

I found this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75208257/1501286) on Stackoverflow , I added this line

```
alias docker-compose="docker compose --compatibility $@"
```

on **.bashrc** and **.profile** but problem is still present

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found from same [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72187587/1501286) this workaround

```
# touch /bin/docker-compose
# echo 'docker compose --compatibility "$@"' > /bin/docker-compose
# chmod +x /bin/docker-compose
```